# Android Emulator run-time error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, android-emulator

**When I execute the android application in Visual Studio 2015 using Xamarin the following error is occurred. Please suggest me to solve this problem..**

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start  
Could not load func glBindFramebuffer  
Could not load func glGenFramebuffers  
Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D  
Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus  
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers  
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer   
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer  
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers  
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers  
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage  
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv  
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer  
Could not load func glGenerateMipmap  
qemu-system-armel.exe: -drive index=0,id=userdata,file=C:\Users\Rupesh\.android\avd\AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\Rupesh\.android\avd\AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\Rupesh\.android\avd\AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img':   Invalid argument
Emulator AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google was stopped.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Emulator you are using is not functional anymore i would suggest you check its settings or just create a new one instead